# Calling post a method of a serializer and passing data to it

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to call a post of a class as shown below by instantiating a view as shown below., i need to write a unit test that calls the post method of this class and not through URL.

```
class SequencingRequestSpreadsheetView(GenericAPIView):

    parser_classes = (JSONParser,)
    serializer_class = SequencingRequestSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsBioUser, )

    suffix = '.xls'
    path = settings.SEQUENCE_REQUEST_SUBMISSION

    def post(self, request, format=None, simulation_mode = False):
```

I need to know how do I create a request object and pass it to this function. 
iam instantiating this view class and I tried passing a request data as json and also tried dictionary but did not work.

how do I create a request object and pass it to this method.

`resp = SequencingRequestSpreadsheetView().post(request)`

Comment: You construct a `HttpRequest` object. But for testing purposes, it is better to use a `Client`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial05/#the-django-test-client

Comment: I think each approach has its "more suitable use case". For instance, if you want to test a view, that receives a request with some values set to `request.session`, Client wont help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RequestFactory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/advanced/#the-request-factory) for achieve what you want.

```
factory = RequestFactory()

# Build a post request. 
request = factory.post(post_url, data, ...)

# Note here that, I don't call the class view directly
# with: 
# SequencingRequestSpreadsheetView().post(request)
# instead I get the view with as_view(), and then pass
# a post request to it.
view = SequencingRequestSpreadsheetView.as_view()

response = view(request, ...)
```

See [Making requests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#making-requests) here to get a better understanding on how RequestFactory works.

Comment: I tried the above method it works but iam getting the below error {'detail': ErrorDetail(string='CSRF Failed: CSRF cookie not set.', code='permission_denied')}

Comment: That's another question ;)